# Importing projects in a BitBucket repository into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, import, bitbucket

I have a BitBucket repository that contains a directory of Eclipse projects, and I am having trouble importing those projects into Eclipse.

The files contained in the repository came from a Subversion repository. They were converted to a Git repository in the usual way, associated with the BitBucket repository using "git clone ", and the BitBucket repository was populated using "git push -u origin master". The Source tab of the repository in my BitBucket account shows all of the files that were contained in the original Subversion repository. To verify that the BitBucket repository was set up right, it did a "git clone " to a different local directory and verified that the new directory had the same files as the directory from which the files were pushed to the BitBucket repository.

Within this repository is a directory containing several Eclipse projects, and I need to import them into Eclipse. To do this, I installed the EGit plugin into Eclipse, switched to Eclipse's Git Repositories view, clicked "Clone a Git repository", entered the url of my BitBucket repository, specified my Workspace directory, and check a box labeled "Import all existing projects after clone finishes". When the clone and import were finished, all of the Eclipse projects were displayed in Eclipse's Package Explorer panel.

Some of the projects display all of their contents correctly, with a project folder containing, among other things, a src folder containing nested package folders that contained Java source files.

The problem is with the other projects, which display a project folder with a greater than ('>') sign between the folder icon and the project name, and a src folder with a greater than sign between the folder icon and the string "src". This folder contains no package folders and no Java source files. Eclipse documentation and forums say that these '>' signs are displayed when a file has been changed since it was last synchronized with a repository (although they mostly talk about these '>' signs being displayed for individual files, not for folders). I tried using the Eclipse command 'Team -> Synchronize Workspace' to make sure that the folders were synchronized, but it didn't change anything. Could anyone tell me what I did wrong along the way that prevents these projects from being imported into Eclipse correctly?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Your Egit config wouldn't include `autocrlf = true`, by any chance? If so, set it to false, and re-clone your repos.

Comment: Neither autocrlf = true nor autocrlf = false worked.

Comment: Ok, just checking there. Do you have any `.gitattributes` in your repo?

Comment: what changes are made in which files? Open the 'git staging' view, every file with changes is listed there.

Comment: The problem turned out to be that some of the projects had .project files that contained this

`<linkedResources>
   <link>
     <name>src</name>
     <type>2</type>
     <location>PROJECT_PATH/src</location>
   </link>
   ....
</linkedResources>`

where PROJECT_PATH was an out of date path to the location of the project's src file. That caused the src subfolder's contents to go unrecognized. The other projects had no such section in their .project files and they were handled right, so I just worked around the problem by deleting that section from the .project files that had it.